# Why is sizeof a char literal not the same as sizeof(char)?

Tags: c, char, sizeof, literals

The program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("sizeof( char ) = %zu, sizeof 'a' = %zu.\n", sizeof( char ), sizeof 'a' );
    return 0;
}
```

outputs the following:

```
sizeof( char ) = 1, sizeof 'a' = 4.
```

I'm compiling with gcc (clang gives the same result) and these flags:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wswitch -pedantic -ansi -std=c11 -DDEBUG -ggdb3 -o
```

Section 6.5.3.4 paragraph 4 of the specification at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf says

> 4 When sizeof is  applied  to  an  operand  that  has  type char, unsigned  char, or signed  char,  (or  a  qualified  version  thereof)  the  result  is  1.

So I would expect sizeof the operand 'a' to be 1 because the type of 'a' is char, or is it being automatically "promoted" to an int, or something similar? (I notice that if I cast 'a' to char then sizeof( (char)'a' ) is 1).

Or am I looking at the wrong standard?

Comment: just in case char a = 'a'; sizeof(a); gives the result of 1

Comment: `a` is exactly equivalent to `97` (on an ASCII-based machine).

Comment: It seems this question has attracted more detailed answers that the linked dup.  It may make sense to reverse the dup.  Since I've answered this question, I'll leave that up to someone else.

Comment: @dbush I agree, I have no idea how that other post got so many up-votes, plus it seems to focus on C vs C++. The oldest posts is not necessarily the best post! I'll vote to re-open.

Comment: Lianne Connolly, C does not have _char literal_.  It does define _character constant_.

Comment: "because the type of 'a' is char," --> No. its an `int` even before promotion considerations.

Comment: Better test code: https://godbolt.org/z/qhYcsoTq3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C opposite to C++ integer character constants (literals) have the type `int`.

So the value of the expression `sizeof( 'a' )` is equal to the value of the expression `sizeof( int )`. While `sizeof( char )` is always equal to `1`.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 4 When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned
> char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is
> 1...

and (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> 10 **An integer character constant has type int.** The value of an
> integer character constant containing a single character that maps to
> a single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the
> representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. The
> value of an integer character constant containing more than one
> character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence
> that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
> implementation-defined. **If an integer character constant contains a
> single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results
> when an object with type char whose value is that of the single
> character or escape sequence is converted to type int.**

Pay attention to that usually objects of the type `char` used in operations as operands or in expressions are converted to the type `int` due to the integer promotions.

Answer (score 5):

Character constants (or more accurately, an *integer character constant*) have type `int`.

Section 6.4.4.4p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes Character Constants:

> An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte
> characters enclosed in single-quotes, as in `'x'`. A wide character
> constant is the same, except prefixed by the letter `L`, `u`, or `U`.
> With  a  few exceptions  detailed  later, the  elements  of  the
> sequence  are any members of the source character set; they are mapped
> in an implementation-defined manner to members of the execution
> character set

And the semantics, which include a description of the type are first described in paragraph 10:

> **An  integer  character  constant  has  type `int`.** The  value  of  an
> integer  character  constant containing  a  single  character  that
> maps  to  a  single-byte  execution  character  is  the numerical  value  of  the  representation  of  the  mapped  character
> interpreted  as  an  integer.
> The  value  of  an  integer  character  constant  containing  more
> than  one  character  (e.g.,
> 'ab'),  or  containing  a  character  or  escape  sequence  that  does
> not  map  to  a  single-byte execution character, is
> implementation-defined.  If an integer character constant contains
> a single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that
> results when an object with
> type `char` whose value is that of the single character or escape
> sequence is converted to type `int`

Answer (score 2):

In C language, `character literal` is not a `char` type. C considers character literal as `integer`. So, there is no difference between `sizeof('a')` and `sizeof(1)`.

size of character literal is equal to size of integer

Comment: C does  not define _character literal_.  It does define _character constant_.

Answer (score 0):

`'a'` has integral type and `sizeof('a')` gives the size of the `int`.